# Edit features using drop down when using Edit widget in web appbuilder

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have an app that displays the tree inventory of a university. The trees have categorical attributes like species, botanical name, etc and numerical attribues like height, diameter etc. When I use the Edit widget to edit the attributes of a tree, I have to type in the new species name. Instead, I would like to edit the categorical fields using a drop-down box that is populated from an excel file. Also, I would like to validate the numerical fields. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Edit Widget will look at the type of attribute column you are editing and show the appropriate input control (text box, select dropdown, numerical input box, etc), so you need to look at the FeatureService that is published and make sure that the attribute columns have the correct types.

To get the select "dropdown" workflow specifically, you should use a [coded value domain](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014561). If you're in ArcGIS Online with a Hosted Feature Service, follow [these instructions](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/define-attribute-lists-and-ranges.htm) to add the coded value domain to your Hosted Feature Service attribute column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to connect 2 attributes? I mean, I need one attribute to update automatically when the other is updated using the Edit widget. I was hoping to get an answer involving editing the web-app code for the OP so I can use the idea to customize the app, but your answer is not wrong.